# Quartz.NET calendars configurable via ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, calendar, quartz.net

I'm creating an application using Quartz.NET, along with an ASP.NET project to add jobs and configure the system. I'd love to be able to utilise Quartz.NET calendars, but I need a way for users to create/configure the calendars via an ASP.NET page. Is there an easy way doing this? Could I use the AJAX calendar control?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a project that does something like you're asking:
http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/06/embeddable-quartznet-web-consoles.html